# How to add React JS's Link paths to DJango URLs backend

Tags: python, reactjs, django, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a project that has React as it's frontend & Django as it's backend. after i integrated React with django it works perfectly but the paths i created in React with react-router-dom doesn't load when i search the page on my browser. meaning, i can load **http://127.0.0.1:8000** comfortably but if i try to search **http://127.0.0.1:8000/rooms/1/UCL** a path that i created with React-router-dom using it's Link, it throws an error calling ***Page not found***
how can i fix this ?

```
#my URL.py
from re import template
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include('api.urls')),
    path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```

my views.py

```
import profile
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from app.models import *
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


@api_view(['GET','PUT'])
def updateRoomData(request,pk):
    try:
        message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)
    except message.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method=='GET':
        serializer = messageSerializer(message)
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = messageSerializer(message, data=request.data)  
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Maybe try `path('*',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))` or similar variant that redirects ***all*** page requests to the root `index.html` file so the React app can load and handle routing/navigation internally. If not that, then check the [CRA deployment doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's anything there that helps explain how to configure the server environment.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on a similar project where react is integrated in the django urls and got the same exact issue.

Thanks to Drew Reese's comment, I was able to use Django's regex url to redirect all other url's to the react application:

```
from django.urls import re_path

...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    re_path(r".*", views.index, name="front"),
]
```

If this doesn't work, then you may need to add the static urls from your react app into urls.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import settings

...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    *static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT),
    re_path(r".*", views.index, name="front"),
]
```

Make sure that STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are also present in `settings.py` and that they link to the right locations.

Here is a source you might want to check out:
https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-django-full-stack-the-best-web-integration-e9d92af43b96

As a final word, I may be missing one or two steps that I'm forgetting, so feel free to ask any questions.